# Запятая/тире/двоеточие

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно это офомить?

`1. – Was habt ihr meiner Sonnenblume angetan, als ich bei der Arbeit war?!`

`– Что?`

`– Я имела в виду, что вы сделали с моим подсолнухом, пока я была, усталая, на работе?`

`2. – Was habt ihr meiner Sonnenblume angetan, als ich bei der Arbeit war?!`

`– Что?`

`– Я имела в виду – что вы сделали с моим подсолнухом, пока я была, усталая, на работе?`

`3. – Was habt ihr meiner Sonnenblume angetan, als ich bei der Arbeit war?!`

`– Что?`

`– Я имела в виду: что вы сделали с моим подсолнухом, пока я была, усталая, на работе?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одно из двух:

***– Я имела в виду: что вы сделали с моим подсолнухом, пока я была, усталая, на работе?***

***– Я имела в виду, что вы сделали с моим подсолнухом, пока я была, усталая, на работе?***

---

Сначала поговорим про второй вариант. Здесь предложение оформлено в виде **косвенной речи**, то есть союзное слово *что* соединяет слова автора и прямую речи.

А в первом варианте оформлено в виде **прямой речи**, но без кавычек, т. к. по правилам, если прямая речь неотличима от косвенной (союзное слово уже есть, после двоеточия), то **кавычки не нужны**.

---

В общем, если вам больше нравится косвенная речь, используйте еë; если нравится прямая речь без кавычек, то, соответственно, берите этот вариант.

Comment: Мне кажется, что, поскольку вторая часть – прямой вопрос (из-за чего и вопросительный знак), надо всё-таки не запятую, а двоеточие ставить-то.

Comment: Если есть вопросительная интонация, то и в косвенной речи вопросительный знак можно ставить-таки.